# Each discrete space is a Polish Space

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to solve exercise 6.3#7 from Sidney A. Morris' ["Topology without tears"](http://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf): "Prove that each discrete space [...] is a Polish space."

I started by proving that discrete spaces are always completely metrizable with the discrete metric. But then I got stuck. As far as I know, the only dense subset of a discrete space is the whole space.

But does that not mean that only *countable* discrete spaces are separable (and therefore Polish) spaces?

Comment: You're right. Polish spaces are second countable by definition and an uncountable discrete space is not second countable.

Comment: Thanks! Just a typo then. Do you want to write it as an answer so that I can give you credit?

Comment: Better yet, write your own answer and (after the necessary lapse of time) accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See t.b.'s comment above confirming my assumption.